# Why does my async task handler for a sqlite database trigger postExecute immediately

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-progressbar

I have an async class that opens up an sqlite database and if is the first time running the database will be populated with data that takes about 10 seconds to complete. Even though there is still working being done in the background the async task finishes immediately. I think it has something to do with the sqlite's oncreate method possibly doing another async task or something

```
class BuildDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Please wait...", "Building database, this may take a few seconds", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // open up the database, if its the first time running the data will
        // be populated
        db = new SQLiteWrapper(ctx); //takes 1-10 seconds
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d(TAG,"post execute");
        loading.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The sqlite helper class main methods look like this

```
public class SQLiteWrapper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public SQLiteWrapper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    ctx = context;

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    // populate our database with data from the zones file
    try {
        database.setLockingEnabled(false);
        buildDatabase(database);
    }
    finally {
        database.setLockingEnabled(true);
    }

}
}
```

If you are familiar with this class onCreate is only called and the database doesn't exist.
If I manually call onCreate() within the database constructor the progress dialog will show.
thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreate` will only be called if you actually *open* the database (and it doesn't yet exist).

Add `this.getWritebleDatabase()` to the `SQLiteWrapper` constructor, like so:

```
public SQLiteWrapper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    ctx = context;
    this.getWritableDatabase();
}
```